# Maytag washer question

Tags: washer

I will be purchasing a new washer in the near future and want to know the cubic feet of the one I will be replacing. I have an old Whirlpool  model no. PAVT920AWW serial no. 26643569JE I have tried looking it up online and I can find parts, manuals, etc. for it but nothing list the cubic feet. Thanks for the help!
Kelly Jo

Comment: I found this answer "3.3 cubic foot capacity" Full name Maytag Performa pavt920aww

Answer (score 3):

This was from Part Select question and answer section. I'm not affiliated with them,

[image]

Comment: Don't understand  the DV?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer

"3.3 cubic foot capacity"

Full name Maytag Performa pavt920aww